# Wrong configuration of AT-SPI in macOS

Tags: macos, python, gtk, macos-highsierra

Working with Python and Gtk+, I'm using Aloe tests to validate the correction of some modules. The tests are designed in such a way that they use the AT-SPI services behind, but in my installation it seems that they can not link the processes.

Next, I show a copy of the error screen in a very simple example (a *Hello World*). The code is completely verified and the tests work correctly on a Linux machine.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Borja:eg seoane$ aloe -x --verbosity=3 features/task1-app.feature
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
Feature: Hello World App

  In order to check if you completed the app in the first part of the assigment
  As a wise person
  I want to validate the app

  Scenario: The app is a Hello World Gtk+ app                                    # features/task1-app.feature:6
    Given I find a file named "holamundo.py"
    When I run "holamundo.py"
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

** (process:843): ERROR **: 09:18:46.379: AT-SPI: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus. Is at-spi-bus-launcher running?
Trace/BPT trap: 5
MacBook-Pro-de-Borja:eg seoane$ 2018-09-20 09:18:46.693 python3[846:26517] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 

(holamundo.py-test-76010700:846): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:18:46.796: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

I installed Aloe through Pip3; and *at-spi2-atk* and *at-spi2-core* through Homebrew.

I don't know what fails in my installation.